As of 2017, are altcoin-specific questions off-topic?
To be clear, I am referring to questions which have nothing to do with Bitcoin like this:
What does one need to do to earn Decred through PoS?
Considering the author (@highly-irregular) has been active here for many years, I'm a bit confused about why this was not even tagged "alternatives", etc.
I have looked through this ancient thread from 2011: Are questions about other crypto-currencies on-topic?, but wonder how relevant that discussion is after 6 years.  This recent discussion on SE naming seems to suggest a tendency towards deprecation of alt-coin related questions.

It has the tag [tag:decred] though?

Thanks @murch, I missed that.  Since we have tags for specific altcoins, it now seems to be pretty clear that such questions are not off-topic.

For the past years, it has been our policy that questions about other cryptocurrencies are on-topic. Since Monero and Ethereum each have their own SE now, we migrate questions about these there.
As you've noted, there's a discussion going on that touches on the scope of this SE: What should this site's name be when we get our new design?
I wouldn't consider the sentiment expressed in some answers of that question to be binding for the scope's site yet, as changing the scope would imho require a topic that explicitly aims to discuss the site's scope.

Properly tagged[1] questions for specific altcoins are not considered off-topic even if they are unrelated to Bitcoin.
[1] Question using a specifically-named tag such as "decred", generic "altcoin" or "alternatives" tags.
